# sensing light and outputing voltage suitable for audio

Tags: light, audio

I have an idea for a project where I use a pc fan to make an oscillator. The oscillation is created by the cycle of light/dark falling on a light sensor as the blades of the fan rotate.

My initial research points to the use of the photodiode in combination with a op-amp to provide a suitable line audio output. My question is: What are the critical parameters for the circuit?

Here is the datasheet for the photodiode i'm prototyping: http://www.jaycar.co.nz/products_uploaded/ZD1948.pdf

Rob

Comment: Gijs Gieskes's work provided inspiration for this project. Check out his site and the videos - some amazing creative stuff.

http://gieskes.nl/
http://vimeo.com/gijs

Comment: There are a lot of simpler ways to make a oscillator.  Why such a kludge?

Answer (score 4):

If you just use a 555 timer you won't need to amplify it, you can plug it directly into a line level input (microphone in on computer, aux in on hifi etc). By putting the photocell on the bottom of the fan and a light source above the fan you could get some interesting results. The speed of the fan would create an oscillation, also the 'brightness' (pitch of harmonic content) of the oscillator could be adjusted by changing the intensity of the overhead light source. Amos is right, you could use a very similar circuit to the one in my Posc, I'll draw up an example just give me a mo....

Comment: It's real easy to fine tune the circuit, you can put a resistor in series with the photocell, or you can change the value of the ceramic capacitor (the smaller the value of your cap, the higher the pitch and brightness of your oscillator). For instance - A 0.1uf cap will take the 555 timer to the limits of the human hearing range when you shine a bright light into the photocell, but when you cover the cell the pitch should be lower than the human hearing range and will be audible as pulses not tones.

Comment: You can also use a similar trick to listen to the discreet frequencies found in the laser of an optical mouse. Just hold the laser on the photocell of said circuit, and listen to the crazy noises!

Comment: To be exact, it's making a square wave oscillator to create a tone, then your using the fan to modulate the pitch of that tone. It's not a sine wave by any means, but you won't get that from a PC fan! I'm positive it would make a pretty great sounding oscillator tho

Answer (score 2):

The critical parameters are the light and dark currents.
The dark current has a maximum value of 30nA. The
light current has a minimum value of 30uA and a 
typical value of 40uA. Since the ratio is 1000:1
there will be a large difference between on and off.

If you use an op-amp to output a line level I would set 
the gain resistor so that a 40uA current gives you 80-90% 
of the line voltage level.

The downside is that the level may be different for different diodes.
You could put a pot in the feedback loop for adjustment.

If you want to get more complicated you could have the
photodiode trigger an analog switch (SPDT). The precise 
line level could be set by adjusting the inputs of the switch.

On the Hamamatsu site there is some good technical information
and application hints for photodiodes.

Comment: Do not count on reaching either the dark current and light current unless you actually reach light and dark, a fan blade will probably not reach these levels, but they are a good place to start.  Plan to have more gain in your pocket.

Comment: Yes, good point, i'll take some measurements with the components in-situ to get an idea of the dynamic range of the photodiode in normal conditions.

Answer (score 2):

[Alex](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/156/alex) who is a member here has details over on his [tinkerlog site](http://tinkerlog.com) of something he calls [Synchronizing Fireflies](http://tinkerlog.com/howto/synchronizing-firefly-how-to/), these may have some useful details in.

But of more use to you is probably [Jim](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/399/jim)'s site [Sonodrome](http://www.sonodrome.co.uk) which has details of his Posc on it. This has two oscillators controlled by light dependent resistors and can output to a stereo. There is a schematic etc in there somewhere.

Comment: I like the use of the ping-pong balls to make the glowing orbs and self organising systems are fascinating in the patterns that emerge.

Comment: Me too, I thought they were fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it's not too clear, but you should get the idea, just ask if you wanna know more.

[image]

Comment: You may need to make a cover/lid for the top, so it limits the overall light going into the box, but that depends on what kind of sound you want.

Comment: If you do make this project, I wanna hear it! (jim@sonodrome.co.uk)
Cheers.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed help Jim. I'll read up about the 555. Lots of work to do!

Comment: Hi Jim, i've documented some testing results here and some questions:
http://mintmedia.co.nz/Fan_oscillator

Comment: Dude! you're totally right, the photodiode is different to the photocell, my bad. It won't work in the same way. The photocell is acting as a variable resistor. Sorry, I'm not too hot on photodiodes

Comment: Also the ground is supposed to be the negative terminal of the battery! I've used them before with an ACDC power adapter, and I didn't bother limiting the current, they were fine.

Comment: If you want more channels you just have to make a mixer and you can add as many as you want, just ask if you want the circuit diagram they're not difficult.

Comment: If you put in a 1KΩ pot between +9v and the photocell, you should have more than enough adjustment of the pitch, bearing in mind the light in the room will play the biggest part in controlling the pitch. If you just pop it on a breadboard first you can have a good mess about with the values, the 555 timer is so robust it's nigh on impossible to break, so don't be scared to just get stuck in.